# focus to image button through jquery on Tab key press not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, imagebutton

HTML:

```
<div class="large-9 columns">
  <input type="text" class="txtsearchbox" name="txtsearch" id="txtsearch" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
  <a class="button expand" id="btnsearch1">
  <img src="/Content/Images/search-16x16.png" id="btnsearch" /></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#txtsearch').on('keydown', function (e) {
        //debugger;
        var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#btnsearch1').focus();
          //  console.log(e.target.href);
        }
    });
```

Here i have one textbox and image button .On Tab key press focus is not shifing or shown on image button ..Am am not getting what the exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the javascript and just add tabindex="0" to "a" tag.

```
<div class="large-9 columns">
    <input type="text" class="txtsearchbox" name="txtsearch" id="txtsearch" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <a tabindex="0" class="button expand" id="btnsearch1">
        <img src="/Content/Images/search-16x16.png" id="btnsearch" />
    </a>
</div>
```